# Django - How to display all items inside a Object

Tags: django, database, object

I have a Profile Object which has a many to many reationship with a Hobbies object. A profile is used for creating a User. Each User can also have a load of hobbies that are predefined. What I want to do is let Users pick some hobbies they are interested in. However, I am not sure how to display all these Hobbies and let Users pick them on the actual display. Here is the code:

```
TYPES = (
        ("Football", "Football"),
        ("Cricket", "Cricket"),
        ("Swimming", "Swimming"),
        ("Cycling", "Cycling")
        )


class Hobby(models.Model):
    myfield = MultiSelectField(choices = TYPES)
```

And the User :

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    email = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    hobbies = models.ManyToManyField(Hobby)
```

And the HTML code I use is here:

```
<span class="fieldname">Hobbies</span>
        {% for hobby in all_hobbies %}
                <input type="checkbox" name={{hobby}} value={{hobby}}> {{hobby}}<br>
        {% endfor %}
```

However this only displays [image]

What I want it to display is all the hobbies with the choices, instead of the whole Object. I am not sure how to do this and would appreciate any help.

Comment: What is the data in the `context` dictionary you are passing to the template?

Comment: I want to list all the hobbies which are defined in the TYPES part of the hobby model

Comment: Are you doing `all_hobbies = Hobby.objects.all()`?

Comment: Try doing `{{ hobby.myfield }}` before the `<br />` tag

Comment: Yes using the objects.all method in the views, trying the hobby.myfield thing now

Comment: It works in that it displays the different hobbies, but without the checkboxes next to each one.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing something like

```
<span class="fieldname">Hobbies</span>
{% for hobby in all_hobbies %}
    <input type="checkbox" name="{{ hobby.myfield }}" value="{{ hobby.myfield }}"> {{ hobby.myfield }}<br />
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Tried this, it only adds a single textbox with multiple values rather then a single textbox for each value.

Answer (score 0):

Under Hobby class, you should add the `str` method that will display the value of your hobby instead of 'Object'

```
def __str__(self):
    return self.myfield
```

You can also use `__unicode__` instead of `__str__` if you are with Python 2.x

**Edit:** 
After I read again your question, I understood that your problem was specifically not having several checkboxes for the multiple choices you have, here is how you can show all the choices, you should pass the hobbies field as a context :

```
{% for value, text in form.hobbies.field.choices %}
  <div class="ui slider checkbox">
    <input id="id_hobbies_{{ forloop.counter0 }}" name="{{ form.hobbies.name }}" type="checkbox" value="{{ value }}"{% if value in checked_hobbies %} checked="checked"{% endif %}>
    <label>{{ text }}</label>
  </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: that returns this error: __str__ returned non-string (type MSFList)